# remove every item of listA from listB

Tags: python, list

I want to remove every item/string that occurs in a listA from listB.

```
list_a = f.readlines()
        for i in xrange(0,len(list_b)):
            if list_b[i] in list_a:
                list_bt[i].pop()
                i--
```

I am sure there is a *better* solution, but as for now, I can't think of one

Comment: do you have duplicates?

Comment: no duplicates in the two lists.

Comment: what do you mean by better? shorter code or faster code in certain scale or scalably faster code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use sets if order does not matter as you have no dups:

```
a = range(15)
b = range(5)

a = set(a).difference(b)
```

If you want a list use `list(a)`

Comment: Note that this solution does not preserve the original list order.

Comment: @Cyber, I have stated that in my answer **You could use sets if order does not matter**

Comment: Using sets is the best answer. Note that you can also use [arithmetic operations on sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) like this `a = a - b`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension as follows.

```
>>> a = [1,6,4,2,4,6,7,3,3,5,9]
>>> b = [2,9,3]
>>> [i for i in a if i not in b]
[1, 6, 4, 4, 6, 7, 5]
```

Comment: Yes, this will assign the generated list back to `a`.

Comment: Note that under the hood this function is doing exactly what you described in your question. This is inefficient for large lists.

Answer (score 1):

Using `filter`

```
>>> a = [1,6,4,2,4,6,7,3,3,5,9]
>>> b = [2,9,3]
>>> filter(lambda x: x not in b,a)
[1, 6, 4, 4, 6, 7, 5]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for element in list_b:
    if element in list_a:
        list_b.remove(element)
```

Comment: This answer could be improved with comments or explanations (it was flagged as not an answer at all), but it is an answer.